# Uncaught ReferenceError: checkbox is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

expected checkbox to be defined as it is the input type.

I am trying to unsubscribe a user with the deleteSubscription function which passes in the dataset to process via the checkboxChanged function.

checkbox in html:

```
     <div class="ml-3 flex h-5 items-center">
      <% subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, user_digest_id: user_digest.id) %>
      <input onchange="checkboxChanged(this)" <%= 'checked' if subscriber %> data-subscriber-id="<%= subscriber.try(:id) %>" data-user-digest-id="<%= user_digest.id %>" id="<%= user_digest.id %>_subscribed_status" name="subscribed" type="checkbox" class="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-brand-teal focus:ring-brand-teal-dark">
    </div>
```

checkbox used in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkboxChanged(checkbox) {
    let userDigestId = checkbox.dataset.userDigestId;

    if (checkbox.checked) {
      createSubscription(userDigestId);
    }
    else {
      let subscriberId = checkbox.dataset.subscriberId;
      deleteSubscription(userDigestId, subscriberId);
    }
  }
  function createSubscription(userDigestId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/subscribers',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {subscriber: {user_digest_id: userDigestId} },
      success: function(data){
        let subscriberId = data.subscriber_id;
        let userDigestId = data.user_digest_id;
        let checkbox = document.getElementById(userDigestId + '_subscribed_status')
        checkbox.dataset.subscriberId = subscriberId;
      }
     })
    }
 
 function deleteSubscription(userDigestId, subscriberId) {
    console.log('TO DO: unsubscribe user');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/subscribers/'+ subscriberId,
      method: 'DELETE',
      data: { subscriber: { user_digest_id: userDigestId } },
      success: function(data){
        console.log('received response from DELETE subscriber request');
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

expected checkbox and checkbox.dataset to return something in console

Comment: I looks like `data` in the ajax success method is not an object

Comment: Have you done some debugging - e.g. console.log of data to check its items are what you expect them to be?

Comment: There are three things you really should do right away to make this code easier to debug, fix and maintain. The first is to move the database query out of the view and into the controller. The second is to use the tag helpers instead of  making your markup into a soup of HTML and erb. The third is to simply move this script into the assets pipeline and and use an event hander instead of inline JS and globals.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not coming from this code. `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` means that you're trying to reference a variable that has not been declared. However, in this code, `checkbox` is always declared before being used.

Even if the program was failing and the script wasn't receiving the object it's expecting, the error message would be different. It would read `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`, because even if the variable is empty, it's still being declared.

The error is either coming from another part of the code that wasn't shared here, or you may accidentally be running a previous version of this code where you had not declared the variable before using it.